# Trigger function from checkbox checked, without using .change()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a dynamically loaded table where each row has a checkbox option, with an assigned #id of either 1,2 or 3. I need to make a function that will shows a hidden div corresponding to the #id of the checkbox checked. I'm currently using .change() to trigger the function, but this ends up showing the hidden div when unchecking a box, which I do not want to happen. Is there another way to trigger this function for just on "checked", and not "unchecked". See code below:

```
<tr>
   <td >
      <input id="1" class="link_contact" type="checkbox"/>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td >
      <input id="2" class="link_contact" type="checkbox"/>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td >
      <input id="3" class="link_contact" type="checkbox"/>
   </td>
</tr>

<div class="1" style="display:none;"> Some Hidden Text</div>
<div class="2" style="display:none;"> Some Hidden Text</div>
<div class="3" style="display:none;"> Some Hidden Text</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".link_contact").change(function () {
        $("." + $(this).attr('id')).fadeIn(800);
        $("." + $(this).attr('id')).delay(7000).fadeOut(800);
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `:checked` selector with in the function `is()`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".link_contact").change(function () {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
             $("." + $(this).attr('id')).fadeIn(800);
             $("." + $(this).attr('id')).delay(7000).fadeOut(800);
             $('.dialog_warning').fadeOut(800);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

check this http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: Thank you! All give you the answer asap!

Answer (score 4):

Do the actions only if the checkbox is checked

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".link_contact").change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $("." + this.id).stop(true, true).fadeIn(800).delay(7000).fadeOut(800);
            $('.dialog_warning').fadeOut(800);
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XetMs/)

Answer (score 0):

Missing ending quote (after style attribute) in your html tag

```
<div class="3" style="display:none;> Some Hidden Text</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that was just a typo. Not what I was looking for.

Comment: This missing quote cause the bug ;)